# Powershell mandatory parameters, I am a newbie to PowerShell scripting

Tags: powershell

I have task on my ci/cd that calls below powershell script meant to stop a function before other deployment tasks on the same job. The script seem to throwing error even though I have all the variables correctly set. Please help and many thanks in advance..

```
#####Script#######
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $XxxxFunctionAppName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $ResourceGroupName
)
#stoping function app
$trap = Get-AzFunctionApp -Name $XxxxFunctionAppName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($trap.state -eq "Running")
{
Stop-AzFunctionApp -Force
}

####Error message#####
2021-04-06T10:24:43.3332161Z ## Validating Inputs
2021-04-06T10:24:43.3390381Z ## Validating Inputs Complete
2021-04-06T10:24:43.4262841Z ## Initializing Az module
2021-04-06T10:24:43.6949853Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2021-04-06T10:24:44.0148107Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.9.0\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2021-04-06T10:24:44.9908767Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2021-04-06T10:24:45.5333784Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2021-04-06T10:24:45.9446194Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2021-04-06T10:24:46.9272395Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -TenantId ***
2021-04-06T10:24:47.4342523Z ## Az module initialization Complete
2021-04-06T10:24:47.4352242Z ## Beginning Script Execution
2021-04-06T10:24:47.4690205Z ##[command]& 'c:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r241\a\_xxxxxxxxxxxx\Scripts\Stopxxxx.ps1' -xxxxFunctionAppName "func-xxxxx-develop-02" -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx-develop-rg"
2021-04-06T10:24:50.7841003Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2021-04-06T10:24:51.2391709Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2021-04-06T10:24:51.8052164Z ##[error]Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name ResourceGroupName.
2021-04-06T10:24:51.8527691Z ##[section]Finishing: StopxxxxFunc
```

Comment: How do you call the script? (Don't use brackets and comma's between the parameters when you call it)

Comment: This is how I am calling it $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Xxxx-Infrastructure/Scripts/StopXxxxFunc.ps1 and then add script parameters as -XxxxFunctionAppName "$(XxxxFunctionAppName)" -ResourceGroupName "$(ResourceGroupName)"

Comment: Is `ResourceGroupName` a function or a variable? If it is a variable, it should be: `$ResourceGroupName`, if it is a function, make sure it is populated.

Comment: It is a variable like -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName on the script

Comment: You need to pass it an actual value and not the variable you created for the parameter: `-XxxxFunctionAppName "MyFunction AppName" -ResourceGroupName "resourceGrouptesta" `

Comment: The idea is to have it pick up variables scoped to particular environment as the pipeline promotes code from dev to prod. So ideally would not want to hard code these values but should be picked up from the variable groups. Hope that make sense. Many thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't. So can you draw it out for us and in regards to pasting the rest of your code on how you're trying to *"pick up variables scoped to particular environemt as the pipeline promotes code from dev to prod"*? Sorry, just having a trouble understanding it

Comment: Sorry Abraham I know my explanation can be confusing, but what I mean is: I have four environments like dev, test, stage and prod. The naming convention i use mean that the function to be stopped and the resource group where it leave is/are different and named according the environment like dev-func, pro-func or dev-rg, prod-rg.

Comment: So I want my script to be able to execute in all these environment and using the right environment name for both function and resource group name which are configure on variable group and task groups. As it progress from one environment to another using just variables like $ResourceGroupname and $XxxxFuncAppName. Let me know if that make sense or I just added more confusion. Many thanks

Comment: I should not hard code these variables but pick them up on their respective environment